# Regular expression to match a simple logic of getting the proper digits from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Here I have a several different strings with salaries:

```
"U3 000 Per Month"
"U10 000 - U12 000 Per Month"
"U12 000 Per Month"
"U125 000 - U130 000 Per Month"
"U130 000 Per Month"
```

I'm trying to build a regex using the following logic:

Match the **first** 1,2 or 3 digits that come after **first** U letter only, then match zeros that come after a single space after **first** 1,2 or 3 digit group. The rest of the string doesn't matter. For example, we have few strings:

```
"U20 000 - U30 000 Per Month"
"U3 000 Per Month"
"U125 000 - U130 000 Per Month"
```

I want a regex to return

> 20000, 3000, 125000

Please help, I'm too exhausted of digging Regex documentation

Comment: Doesn't `(?<=^U)\d{1,3}\s0*` work?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Great! It does, but with a little adjustment. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with [(?<=^U)\d{1,3}\s0*](http://rubular.com/r/3zAHylGXqI).

```
regex = /(?<=^U)\d{1,3}\s0*/
p 'U20 000 - U30 000 Per Month'.scan(regex).first.sub(/\s/, '') # "20000"
p 'U3 000 Per Month'.scan(regex).first.sub(/\s/, '') # "3000"
p 'U125 000 - U130 000 Per Month'.scan(regex).first.sub(/\s/, '') # "125000"
```

I thought in only zeros after the `\s`, so as you've added `\d{1,3}` would fit better.